# x:name of controls in ApplicationViewStates

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am working in windows store apps and I need help..
I am trying to adapt my app for the differents visual state (FullScreenLandscape, FullScreenPortrait, Snapped, etc) and I need to reuse the controls for each visual state..

I create a grid for each visual state for example

```
        <Grid x:Name="PortraitView" Visibility="Collapsed">

        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="FillView" Visibility="Visible">

        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="SnapView" Visibility="Collapsed">

        </Grid>
```

but my problem is that I can not repeat the x:name of the controls that I set in the Grid= PortraitView..

how can I resolve it?

thanks

Comment: Why would you need to have same names of different elements?

Comment: @FilipSkakun no, for example in the FillView i have a button with x:name="btnTest" and i need this button for the SnapView and PortraitView (i need to adapt the button for the application state).. how i do this?

Comment: You have multiple buttons that use the same `Click` event handler or same `Command` binding.

Comment: @FilipSkakun it is true, but if I have a textbox ? example: I need to create a new user (some textboxs with their values), in this case I need to create four methods? one per ApplicationView ?? because if you say to me that I change de x:name of the controls.. I do not know if you understand me..

Comment: @FilipSkakun the solution is create UC for each ApplicationView with the same x:name of controls? I do not know what do.. sorry I am a beginner in store apps

Comment: Oh, the easiest way is to use the binding markup extension. You create a simple view model class with properties for the different fields in your view, then set the `DataContext` of your page to an instance of the view model and in your view (page) set things like `<TextBox Text="{Binding FieldText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>` assuming your view model has a property called FieldText. Make sure the view model implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raises `PropertyChanged` event in the property setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN

> The most common usage of this property is to specify a XAML element
>   name as an attribute in markup. This property essentially provides a
>   WPF framework-level convenience property to set the XAML x:Name
>   Directive.
>
> **Names must be unique within a namescope.**
>
> For more information, see [XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx).